# What effects do the different AVAudioQuality options have on the resulting recording?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, audio-recording

Part of the app I'm building involves audio recording. Here is the relevant code:

```swift
let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue]

audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: self.audioFilename, settings: settings)
```

I want the quality to be as good as possible, but I want to allow the user to change the quality in settings if it would save space.

What do the different values of AVAudioQuality actually do? Would they make the files smaller as quality goes down? And is the same true for sample rate? A lot of the tutorials I've seen use around 12000 for sample rate though I know professional recording is usually 44100, is there a reason not to use 44100?

Answer (score 7):

I will translate the graphics above, to how it works in practice [on the recorded sound]. 
The audio sampling rate affects the frequency range that will be recorded, the higher the sampling rate is, the higher the audio frequencies possible to be recorded.

That sampling number is based on PCM (Pulse Code Modulation) used to digitalise the sound. The higher it is, the better is the curve definition (as displayed on the drawings above)

But what a better curve means in practice?
A better curve means more details on high frequencies of audio. You can record a clearer sound, specifically on treble frequencies.

Why 44100 and what does this number means? Is there a way for you to mentally figure out how a recording using lower [22050, 11000, 8000] sample rate would sound?

Yes, there is.

A human ear is capable of hearing from 20Hhz to 20000Hhz [a perfect ear, on a very young person, can reach up to 20000Hz, kids for example]

All other adult humans can hear about 20Hhz to 17500Hhz (this is an average)

When we digitalise a sound, if we want it to be the most perfect for the human hearing, we need to be able to digitalise the full frequency range which the human ear is capable to hear. Which is from 20Hhz to 20000Hhz.

Being short here, without going into deep details about how PCM works, the mathematical and practical rule is: **"The sampling rate must be the double of the audio frequency to be able to record that audio frequency digitally"**

Which means: To be able to digitally record a treble sound of 18000Hhz you need a sampling rate of 36000Hz (the double of it, always)

This is why the number 44100 is 44100: it is the double of 20000Hhz [maximum human hear capacity] (plus a little)

So a sampling rate of 44100 is capable of digitalising and recording audio frequencies in a range from 20Hz up to 22000Hz, this is just above the maximum human capacity, which means: a perfect sound! (* for us humans)

If you set the application sampling rate around 12000, it will permit you to record sound frequencies up to 6000Hhz. You will loose most of the treble of the sound.

A telephone talk, for example, is digitally sampled at 8000, which makes it capable of transmitting sound frequencies up to 4000Hz. It is good for talking, but it misses a lot of higher frequencies above 4000Hz. There is no treble sound on telephones because of that.

Now you can mentally figure out how the sampling rate affects the resulting recorded sound. From 4000Hz of the telephone sound quality, up to 15200Hz of any FM Radio station, up to 20000Hhz of any CD quality sound.

Choose the desired maximum audio frequency range that you want/need to be able to record, and double the value: and you will know the correct sampling rate you will have to adjust on your application.

You asked if is there any reason not to be 44100. It depends on the finality of the recorded sound. For voices, just voices, to record people talking, 12000 is good enough: it is not so bad as a telephone, it will record sound frequencies up to 6000Hz which is the tune of most voices, and it will cut all other higher frequencies above 6000Hz (bird sounds, distracting sounds, metal sounds, etc). So 12000 and is better for recording people voices than 44100. Let's consider on a restaurant, with all eating noises and glass noises, to record voices is better a lower sampling rate, to eliminate all those treble sounds and record better just the voices.

For music, always choose 44100.

About file size, yes, the lower the sampling rating is, smaller the resulting audio file will be. But you are using AAC compression, so there is no need to worry about file size:

- 1min AAC recording [2 channels] at 44100 is about 950KB
- 1min AAC recording [2 channels] at 12000 is about 280KB
- 1 Hour AAC recording [2 channels] at 44100 is abt 57MB

What about sampling greater than 44100? There is 48000, 96000, or even greater.

A sampling of 48000 will allow sound frequencies up to 24000hz (no super-human is capable of hear such kind of high frequency sound) You will just end up with a bigger file.

A sampling of 96000 will allow sound frequencies up to 48000Hz, well only a **dog** is capable of hearing such treble sounds up to 45000Hz. A sampling of 96000 is good to record sounds that when reproduced will sound exactly like real sound, but for the Dog ears. For us there is no difference from the 44100 sampling rating. Our ear cannot distinct. (PS: Valid to mention for this case, is that you would need a speaker capable of reproducing sounds above 20000Hz, which is very difficult to find..)

*PS: Sampling rate is measured in Herts, like sound frequencies also are. 
I intentionally omitted "Hz" above when referencing to sampling rate while mentioned when referencing to sound frequencies, to avoid confusion with so many look alike numbers, but representing 2 distinct things.*

So, a Sampling of 44100 means 44100Hz [of sampling rate].. and so on..

_

- 1 Hert means 1 (one) oscilation/rotation/event in 1 (one) second interval
- 20000Hz means the sound frequency is oscillating 20 thousand times per second.
- 44100Hz means we are digitalising the sound by taking samples of it at a rate of 44 thousand times per second.

Comment: No one could explain it better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1.AVSampleRateKey is the sampling points taken of the single waveform. that is any sound that is produced is form of a sine waveform and a high quality is determined by its waveform. what sampling does it creates a reference points of the audio signal the less the number the less accurate the waveform is and vice versa.

so for better quality higher number is greater.so the studio professional has 44100 which is 44100 sample for a single waveform. image (c) but more samples creates more size of the audio track.

below image will describe more
[image]

i would suggest to keep the audio sample rate to 44100 and change the paramters of

```
AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
```

depending upon your likings.
Hope this helps